# How did they film the Titanic splitting in half with all the actors on it?

Tags: film-techniques, titanic

In the ***Titanic*** (1997), we know the ship crashed into an iceberg. All havoc broke loose and all sorts of things started to happen.

What I don't understand is how did they manage to film the Titanic splitting in half over a body of water with all the actors on it and the actors starting to slide into the water.

**How did they film the Titanic splitting in half like that?**

[image]

Comment: This and your [other question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79458/43889) are making me genuinely wonder if you understand that what you see in films is not real. That with modern CGI you can produce just about any effect and make it look real.

Comment: This is a serious question?  Someone with 1800+ rep should understand how movies work I would think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A large scale model and computer graphics.

James Cameron was able to get the studio to build a giant water tank on the Mexican coast and had a [full scale model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1997_film)#Scale_modeling) built of the ship (minus a couple of bits which were added using computer graphics). This was all built on top of a lifting platform which allowed the ship to be tilted.

This meant that people really were on a full scale ship which tilted to simulate the sinking.

The part where the ship is ripping in half as enhanced computer graphics applied to the recorded footage, as was the removal of any visible evidence of the water tank, and also the addition of the night sky.

There are quite a lot of [behind the scenes videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ4oY1K9Eqc) on YouTube discussing this.