# How did they film Anakin SkyWalker racing in his podracer at that speed?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In **Star Wars-The Phantom Menace**, we know in the podrace that there are several competitors.

We know that that Anakin's podracer can travel to a speed of up to 895 km/h (I think that is the maximum speed), and he is filmed sitting in his podracer racing inside it across the desert landscape of **Tatooine**.

When he is racing, he is racing at around 895km/h.

The race is shown over some type of closed-circuit broadcast to the fans at the pod race (see 0:57 in the clip below).

**How can racing at this speed be filmed for broadcast to the fans (in-universe)?**

Comment: Never mind how they filmed it, how did they get the entire cast, crew and equipment to Tatooine? SpaceX?

Comment: there are tons of videos of jets breaking the sound barrier, most of which were taken with hand-held cameras. This is not hard to do. Mach 1 is in excess of 900kph at sea level, prob about 1,200kph.

Comment: Weird question. If the pod racers can go up to those speeds, what prevents anything else (like the camera droids in the answer) to fly at similar speeds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Cam Droids

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cam_droid/Legends):

> Cam droids were also used to capture sporting events like *Podraces*, and their recordings would be transmitted to the public HoloNet or portable viewscreens.

[image: J57 cam droid]

Here we see hundreds of cam droids being release at a different pod race (from the same source as above):

[image: Cam droids being released at the Vinta Harvest Classic]

Comment: Assuming you can use Wookiepedia as a somewhat reliable canon source, I'd say this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Camera Droid capable of flying 1,000km/h? They have missile droids after all.

Basically there are two lentisk challenges to overcome here:

- **Recording speed:** At worst you'll end up with a blurry image (flying too fast for recording) or you're overexposing (basically topping the speed of light). Both are a non-issue in-universe I guess since the Earth moves faster and we can still record the night sky.
- **Speed of the observer:** This shouldn't be a problem either. When you're capable of building droids in the shape of spaceships or missiles, which are capable to steer etc. it's just a tiny additional step to add a camera to them.

Also I'm not 100% sure right now, but I think I remember seeing some actual spheric camera droid following people. It's been a while, so might confuse it with one of Darth Maul's seeker droids though.